# C# Back button on visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, back-button

I am creating a quiz for my As level coursework on visual studio 2019(c#). In  this I will be  creating a help button that will have information that the user may need if they are stuck. The button to access the help form will be avaliable through a menu strip bar loacted in the top corner of every form. In the help form there will be a menu strip bar with a back button. I would like to know how to code a back button to go back to the previous form eg Question 1-10 forms or the login form. I know how to code it if i wanted to back to a specific form but it is the fact it may need to back to any form as i dont know which form the user will have previously been on.

Comment: You would use a stack data structure and then push the current form on that as it is shown. When the user presses `back` you pop the top item and show it.

Comment: Your description sounds as if you want to add the button to Visual Studio? But I assume you mean to add it to your application. In this case, please remove the "visual-studio" tag and add the tag relevant to the UI framework you use (e.g. winforms, wpf, asp.net, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to code a back button to go back to the previous form, you can refer to the following code:

Code in Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 newform =  new Form2();
        newform.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
}
```

Code in Form2.cs :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form3 newform = new Form3();
        newform.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Code in Form3.cs :

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    private void btnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form4 newform = new Form4();
        newform.ShowDialog();
        this.Show();
    }
    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

If you want to open other forms, just change this code ‘Form2 newform = new Form2();’.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Commonly, one would store the questions in a list or array. If you also store the index of the current question, then you could use that to return to the correct question.

Answer (score 0):

The button should navigate between different windows:

STEP 1 - add a new button on your current window.

STEP 2 - double click on that button to access cs file:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    

}
```

STEP 3 - create a new object window (to navigate to) and open that, then close current window

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    NewWindow page2= new NewWindow();
    page2.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

You should be able to move between different pages back and forth